# I am getting the text inside my button vertical in multiple lines and not horizontal ,how do i write it in a single line?

Tags: html, css

This the css

```css
.addadminbtn button {
  width: 90%;
  padding-left: 34%;
  padding-right: 28%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(7, 223, 7);
}
```

This is the html

```html
<div class="addadminbtn">
  <button>Add New Admin</button>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated I have given the html and css for my button

Comment: Is there a bounding HTML element for the div "addadminbtn"?
If the bounding element has a set width, or is within other elements with a set width that are not wide enough then the 90% of the actual button doesn't widen the parent elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bounding element has a set width, or is within other elements with a set width that are not wide enough, the 90% of the actual button doesn't widen the parent elements.
You can force, with:

```
.addadminbtn button {
whitespace: nowrap;
}
```

However this is not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with code , text is align in center with single line, if you are checking it on mobile device so use following code

```
.addadminbtn button{
  width:90%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-item:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: rgb(7, 223, 7);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .addadminbtn button {
                width: 90%;
                padding-left: 34%;
                padding-right: 28%;
                padding-bottom: 2%;
                padding-top: 2%;
                font-size: 12px;
                display: flex;
                background-color: rgb(7, 223, 7);
            }
        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="addadminbtn">
            <button>Add New Admin</button>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button element does not have sufficient width to display the text on one line, and without a 'height' property set for the button, it is resizing to display the complete text.

Additionally, by setting the width of the button using a percentage, the button size is being determined by the width of its parent- in this case, your div.

You will need to alter your CSS to provide more width to your button; either by setting the width in 'px' or increasing the width of the parent element, and/or adding a 'height' or 'max-height' property.